# Angularjs ng-value for boolean in select not working

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I would like to use `ng-value="true"` and `false` (boolean) for a select option. But I want to fill the options in php because I am using laravel and the translator. This is my code, and the value is not boolean after I send the form.

```
 <select
      id="job-payed"
      required
      class="form-control"
      name="payed"
      ng-model="payed">
  <option selected disabled value>Please choose..</option>
  <option ng-value="true">Payed</option>
  <option ng-value="false">Not payed</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: i know that i could use an js array, and use ng-options. but i want to fill it in php. 

ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options"

Comment: It will be a string going to your controller. Your controller needs to convert it to a boolean.

Comment: You can use "value" instead of "ng-value". Then use strings 'payed'/'notpayed' in your logic.

Comment: hm, yeah you are right. and there is no way to solve this in a other way?

Answer (score 2):

if someone still gets that problem, try this :

```
<select id="job-payed" required class="form-control" name="payed" ng-model="payed">
    <option selected disabled value>Please choose..</option>
    <option ng-value="{{ true }}">Payed</option>
    <option ng-value="{{ false }}">Not payed</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ng-value="'true'" because ngValue should contain an expression to the value of

If you use ng-value="true" angular will look for variable called true in your scope($scope.true)

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue

Answer (score 0):

This works on **select boxes** as expected **starting in Angular 1.6.0**. Prior versions' ng-value treat the values as Strings in select boxes.

Angular 1.5.0: https://plnkr.co/edit/G52M9yaAgJjfVj82i3YF?p=preview

Angular 1.6.0: https://plnkr.co/edit/nyI4ENLW1h0z3JuyDYWO?p=preview

Update the version in the plunk to see how the types change:

```
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
```